# Reverse migration / drop foreign key for custom index name laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

So I have this migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('xxx', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('aaa','bbb') // handle identifier name too long
                ->references('id')->on('aaa_table')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

I want create the `down()` function / reverse the migration for remove this foreign key.

What I have tried here:

```
public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('xxx', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // implement one line of all 4 possibilities
            $table->dropForeign(['aaa']);
            $table->dropForeign(['bbb']);
            $table->dropForeign(['aaa'], 'bbb');
            $table->dropForeign(['bbb'], 'aaa');
        });
    }
```

All giving the same error when I run rollback this migration file,

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'zzz'; check that column/key exists
```

The database condition is still clean, no data (row) inserted. If I do it without the custom name assigned to second argument in `foreign` and short name case (no warning abount identifier name too long), the reverse migration runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

> Alternatively, you may pass an array containing the column name that
> holds the foreign key to the dropForeign method. The array will be
> automatically converted using the constraint name convention used by
> Laravel's schema builder:
>
> $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);

for our case, it should be:

```
$table->dropForeign(['aaa','bbb']);
```

**but this will not be true for your case because of:**

the method [foreign](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_foreign) take two parameters, one as columns names, other as foreign key name.

in your case, you use one column for relation and the other for naming!

```
  $table->foreign('aaa','bbb')
```

it should be:

```
  $table->foreign(['aaa','bbb'])
```

alternatively you could make it like:

```
 $table->foreign(['aaa','bbb'],'my_foreign_name')....
```

and in down() method

```
  $table->dropForeign('my_foreign_name');
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it still generates the same error

Comment: do you have phpstorm?

Answer (score 1):

## For those dealing with indexes

Let's say you created your foreign key column using following migration:

```php
Schema::table('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDeleteCascade()
        ->onUpdateCascade();
});
```

With this migration, Laravel said to MySQL - Create foreign key **constraint** on column named `user_id`.

However, some databases, like MySQL will automatically create **index** for any newly created foreign key **constraint**. Please note difference between having index and constraint... they are two standalone DB elements!

Dropping foreign key **constraint** does not mean, foreign key **index** has been dropped as well! You need to drop it separately.